# $y$-component of center of a cube that rolls without slipping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, geometry, coordinate-systems

[image]

For the figure above, let $O$ be the origin point for $x,y$-axis, and $+x$ goes to the horizontal right direction while $+y$ direction goes to the up direction.

The figure has one circle and one cube, each with radius $r$ and side length $2b$. Center of circle is $O$ and center of cube is $C$. Suppose that circle remains in place, while the cube rolls around the circle without slipping.

I do get that $B$'s y-component is $(b+r)\cos \theta$, but how does one actually get the y-component of location of $C$?

Mass density is assumed to be constant.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not a physics problem, it's pure geometry.
Secondly, posting homeworks is something, that's not so much welcome here.

However, I'll help you out. It's quite simple:

If the box started rolling when the **center** of it's base was touching the top of the ball, then these lengths (drawn red on the figure) will be equal. Their length is $r \theta$ (the length of the arc). The length $CB$ is also the same and it makes angle $\theta$ with the horizon. So finally your $y$ component is $(b+r)\cos \theta+CB sin\theta=(b+r)\cos \theta+r\theta sin\theta$.

[image]